# Get-ChildItem Adding a Exclude filter for Assembly.*.dll but include Assembly.Some.*.dll

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a requirement where I want to exclude all the assemblies which are having pattern

```
Assembly.*.dll
```

but want to include all the assemblies having pattern

```
Assembly.Some.*.dll
```

from the same location through `Get-ChildItem`.

I want to achieve this functionality in a single line of script.

Comment: If you have the filter to only include `Assembly.Some.*.dll` won't that, by definition, exclude `Assembly.*.dll`?

Comment: Please share what have you already tried. [So] is not free code writing service so showing your own effort would be appreciated

Comment: Hi @robdy, I think you thought too much about your talent else you won't ask that silly question on a reputed website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `-or` operator inside a `Where-Object` filter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll |Where-Object {
  $_.Name -like 'Assembly.Some.*.dll' -or $_.Name -notlike 'Assembly.*.dll'
}
```

Since any assembly with a name like `Assembly.Some.Namespace.dll` will already return true on the first condition, the second condition won't be tested

Comment: Since their question specifies single-line, you can also use the array `Where` method: `@(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll).Where{$PSItem.Name -like 'Assembly.Some.*.dll' -or $PSItem.Name -notlike 'Assembly.*.dll'}`